# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(), but I'm not test wohle arrays for truth

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I get this error message but I'm not testing whole arrays. My minimum running code:

```
from dolfin import *
import time, numpy, sys

# parameters
eps = 10e-6

# dimensions in meter
l = 100.0
b = 6.0
h = 3.0

# create mesh
mesh = BoxMesh(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, l, h, b, int(l), int(h), int(b))
print mesh
# functionspace
V = VectorFunctionSpace(mesh, "CG", 2)
boundary_parts = FacetFunction("uint", mesh)
boundary_parts.set_all(0)

# boundary conditions
class BCLeftRight (SubDomain):
    def inside(self, x, on_boundary):
        return on_boundary and ((x[0] <= eps) or (x[0] >= l-eps))

n = 41 
steps = numpy.linspace(10,90,n)
i = 0
while i<n:
    class BCTop (SubDomain):
        def inside(self, x, on_boundary):
            return on_boundary and x[1] >= h-eps and x[2] >= b-3-eps and ((
            x[0] >= steps[i]-9.0-15-eps and x[0] <= steps[i]+9.0-15+eps) or (
            x[0] >= steps[i]-9.0+15-eps and x[0] <= steps[i]+9.0+15+eps))#this line produces the error message
    boundary_parts.set_all(0)

    bcLeftRight = BCLeftRight()
    bcTop = BCTop()
    bcLeftRight.mark(boundary_parts, 1)
    bcTop.mark(boundary_parts, 2)
    u0 = Constant((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    bc0 = DirichletBC(V, u0, boundary_parts, 1)
    ds = Measure("ds")[boundary_parts]

    # define variational problem
    u = TrialFunction(V)
    v = TestFunction(V)
    f = Constant((0.0, -10000, 0.0))
    a = inner(grad(u), grad(v))*dx
    L = inner(f, v)*dx + inner(f, v)*ds(2)
    #L = inner(load, v)*ds(2)

    # Compute solution
    b = None 
    A = assemble(a)
    u = Function(V)
    b = assemble(L, tensor=b, exterior_facet_domains=boundary_parts) 
    bc0.apply(A, b) 
    solve(A, u.vector(), b)
    i = i+1
```

This code reproduces the error. Strange is: If I leave the while-loop away I don't get the error message. I already tried "&" and "|" and "logical_and" and "logical_or" and brackets"()". I would be happy for quick advice.

Comment: Please edit the answer to include a copy of the whole error message.

Comment: The whole error message is in the subject line (not the best place).  What we really need is the line where the error occurs.  That is marked,  but nearly off screen.

Comment: Did you ever test the offending line in an interactive shell? using an array of similar shape to `x`?

Comment: The "Related" list on the right of my web page shows *many* duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

I think operator order is giving you problems.

`x>1 and x<3` produces an error because it is evaluated as `(x>1 and x)<3`.  `(x>1) & (x<3)` is the correct expression.

This error message comes up frequently on SO, though this () order cause isn't quite so common.

I nearly missed the comment that flagged the error line.  The comment is way off screen:

```
x[0] >= steps[i]-9.0-15-eps and x[0] <= steps[i]+9.0-15+eps) or (
        x[0] >= steps[i]-9.0+15-eps and x[0] <= steps[i]+9.0+15+eps))
```

try:

```
(x[0] >= steps[i]-9.0-15-eps) & (x[0] <= steps[i]+9.0-15+eps)) | (
        (x[0] >= steps[i]-9.0+15-eps) & (x[0] <= steps[i]+9.0+15+eps)))
```

You had the right () in

```
return on_boundary and ((x[0] <= eps) or (x[0] >= l-eps))
```

The key is to make sure the logical comparisons are performed first.  You may still have to change `and/or` to `^/|`.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the fault. It was the

```
x[2] >= b-3-eps
```

which I had to modify to

```
x[2] >= 2.99
```

Now it works but I don't know why this piece of code was a problem. I had brackets arround the comparisons before but the error still ocurred. thanks for your help.